# How can I run testNG through a call from another method, let's say a main method?

Tags: java, testng, reportng

How can I run testNG through a call from another method, let's say a main method?
If I am coding an application to have data from UI and saving it in an excel sheet. Then I execute a test suite through a call to that methods, then I generate reports using reportNG ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tests from the TestNG project itself will provide you some good examples like [ListenerTest](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/test/java/test/listeners/ListenerTest.java).

```
TestNG tng = new TestNG();
tng.setTestClasses(testClasses);
tng.run();
```